# Problem setting window.onload and window.onresize

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = widthFunction();
    window.onresize = function widthFunction(){
        var viewportWidth;
        var fouronefour;
        rotdiv = document.getElementById("rotationdiv");
        viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
        fouronefour = 414;
        if(parseInt(viewportWidth) < parseInt(fouronefour))
        {rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";}
        }
</script>

<body>
<div id="rotationdiv" style="visibility:collapse;">If you would like to see more columns, click <a href="WiderPage.aspx">here</a>.</div>
</body>
```

I know there is a problem with `window.onload = widthFunction();`. What I basically want this function to do is "on load and on resize, check the screen size. if the screen size is more than 414px, display the div asking the client to go to a wider page."

It's a gridview with many boundfields. I figured I'd try this because I'm scaling my website down to a mobile browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";
```

Should be

```
rotdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: this is where i had no idea on, and changing this (as well as separating the function from the `window.onload` and `window.onresize`) made it function perfectly.

though, is there any reason why `rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";` doesn't work?

Comment: yeah, it just doesn't work that. style is an object, of type `CSSStyleDeclaration`. So setting that as a string isn't allowed. It seems like it should be the attribute, but it's not

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the parens in your first line.

```
window.onload = widthFunction;
```

As it is, it's setting the *return* of widthFunction to the onload event - which is undefined.

edit:
Actually, if your browser is implementing JS correct (as in you aren't in IE) I believe that this still won't work - the name `widthFunction` will not be defined outside the function itself. You would have to define widthFunction externally first, with

```
function widthFunction() {
    ...
}
```

or

```
var widthFunction = function() {
    ...
}
```

Also, why are you setting 414 to a weirdly named variable, and then `parseInt`ing it? Your parseInt's aren't doing anything since you're working with number types already. Also, if you're going to put 414 into a variable, you might as well give it a more meaningful name. "fouronefour" doesn't help in getting rid of magic constants.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like:

```
function widthFunction(){
    var viewportWidth;
    var fouronefour;
    rotdiv = document.getElementById("rotationdiv");
    viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    fouronefour = 414;
    if(parseInt(viewportWidth) < parseInt(fouronefour))
    {rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";}
} 
window.onresize = window.onload = widthFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onresize = function widthFunction(){...}
```

You are setting `window.onresize` to a function, but `widthFunction` doesn't do anything here.  This will not create a function called `widthFunction`.

So, in the line:

```
window.onload = widthFunction();
```

`widthFunction` is undefined, because it was never defined.

What you want to do is, first declare `widthFunction`:

```
function widthFunction(){
   var viewportWidth;
   var fouronefour;
   rotdiv = document.getElementById("rotationdiv");
   viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
   fouronefour = 414;
   if(parseInt(viewportWidth) < parseInt(fouronefour)){
       rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";
    }
}
```

Then set `window.onresize` and `window.onresize` to it:

```
window.onload = widthFunction;
window.onresize = widthFunction;
```

EDIT: There are some things bugging me with the `widthFunction` function.

Why are you making a variable called `fouronefour`?  Just use `414`.  Also, you don't need `parseInt` there.

```
if(viewportWidth < 414){ // window.innerWidth returns you a number, not a string
```

Also, this:

```
rotdiv.style = "visibility:visible;";
```

should be:

```
rotdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
```